# Error compiling react native router flux with latest react native

Tags: react-native

I have just upgraded react native from 0.64.2 to 0.69.1.

After `npm run android` I bumped into this,

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-router-flux\src\index.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
RouterComponent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.codebox57.connextion&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:113165:36
```

Any one had this problem? How to remove this error?